# Android HttpURLConnection to get a JSON with azurewebsites

Tags: android, json, gson, httpurlconnection

I try to connect to this URL:

http://551bba54-0ee0-4-231-b9ee.azurewebsites.net/api/values

with this simple code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(http://551bba54-0ee0-4-231-b9ee.azurewebsites.net/api/values).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();
        Response response = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()), classOfResult);
        if (response != null)
            return response;
        }
}
```

The response is always "null". I don't know why.

I tried to use also:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

with no effect.

If I open the URL in my browser, this is the response (a correct JSON response)

```
[{"Codice":"P1"},{"Codice":"P2"}]
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try to call `connection.getInputStream()` before the `.connect()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
private void sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=mkyong";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
```

from http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: It works!!! To have a "Response", I add BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
StringBuilder responseS = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseS.append(inputLine);
                }
                br.close();
Response response = gson.fromJson(responseS.toString(), classOfResult);

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am happy to hear that :)